# Displaying the highest count number in column in database using Cakephp 2x

Tags: php, cakephp

I am using cakephp 2x and I'm trying to display the max count of my "Users" table

heres my controller

```
    $getid = $this->User->find('all',
        array('fields' => array('Max(User.id)'))
        );

    $users = $this->set('users',$getid);
```

its not working.

Answer (score 0):

Max count ? you mean the last id when i see your function .

If yes,

You must use getLastInsertId function on your model

```
Example : $this->User->getLastInsertID()
```

Normally that must do the job

Or you can also find the first user by order desc

```
$this->User->find('first',
        array('fields' => User.id','order' => array('User.id' => 'desc)))
);
```